# php sybase Allowed memory size exhausted?

Tags: php, memory, sybase, freetds

I'm getting this problem while trying to run any query against Sybase from php:

- PHP 5.4.3 (cgi-fcgi) (built: May  9 2013 17:03:23)
- built --with-sybase-ct=/path/to/freetds
- code:

```
    <?php
    $con = sybase_connect('server', 'user', 'pwd'); //connects fine
    $q = sybase_query("select col=1", $con);        //error here, regardless of SQL
    ?>
```

- Output:
  **Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to 
  allocate 30064771074 bytes)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your code :

```
<?php
    ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
    $con = sybase_connect('server', 'user', 'pwd'); //connects fine
    $q = sybase_query("select col=1", $con);        //error here, regardless of SQL
    ?>
```

Comment: 128M didn't help. I looked at the error message (tried to allocate part) and gave: ini_set("memory_limit","30G");  That helped, but why in the world would it require 30G to query ??

Comment: There should be a problem in your query, try to optimize it, what are you trying to achieve with `select col=1` ? should you specify a table and a database first ?

Comment: 'select col=1' is a valid sql that should return 1 row. I'm just using it as an example that can be easyly reproduced. Like I stated in my post, I'm getting the same error message regardless of the SQL used.